# Capistrano and Ubuntu Service

Tags: ubuntu, service, ssh, capistrano, nohup

After a few days and much google searching, I have finally solved an issue of mine. I'm using Railsless-deploy (capistrano without the rails tasks/goodies) so I can deploy a project thats' not in rails.

In order to start/stop/restart the server, I have already made a init.d service that works fine in ssh, but I had to use nohup to make it work:

```
namespace :deploy do
 task :start, roles: :app, except: { no_release: true } do
   sudo "nohup service app start"
 end
 desc "Stops the app"
 task :stop do
  sudo "nohup service app stop"
 end
 desc "Restarts the app"
 task :restart do
   sudo "nohup service app restart"
 end
end
```

I have a quick 2 questions, do I have to add an ampersand (&) after the command link this: `sudo "nohup service app restart &"`. I'm not using it, now, and it seems to be working fine. Also is there a way to get back the actual output so I know that the service could be started or anything? As of right now it gives the generic warning:

```
 ** [out :: 0.0.0.0] nohup:
 ** [out :: 0.0.0.0] ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'
```

I'd like to actually see the actual output that I get when I run the command when logged in by ssh.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind there are two things about capistrano: It doesn't require a tty to login and it's default shell is sh. The other thing is perhaps it's hanging on sudo itself, waiting for a password. sudo as a command is deprecated, #{sudo} or {#try_sudo} is ok.

My bet is that one of these issues is causing your service not to startup properly.

Rather than abusing nohup:

```
run "#{sudo} service app start", { :shell => 'bash'}
```

Or run with a tty (usually set in the capfile):

```
default_run_options[:pty] = true
```

Run with just a pty on your command:

```
run "#{sudo} service app start", { :pty => true}
```

Adding "&" to the end of the command will just tell the server to background the process, and you won't get any output.

Comment: Hmm, I'm already running it with pty set to true. So is sudo a command anymore or not? I get confused cause I can't find like a document of all of the commands. And I know I dont' need a password with my sudo (btw the sudo method works fine within needing to be run inside of run).

Do you think I have to declare to run with bash? I'm also looking at using Capistrano V3, instead, but I believe some of the API greatly changed since now they inherit from Rake::Application.

Comment: I think you are getting some sort of interactive prompt that is stopping your script from the init.d script.

Comment: No, i don' think so. I watched the app's log and when I told it to restart, it DID shut down the server, but it didn't wait to restart. So that's why I had to use nohup so that it would continue to function in the background AFTER my SSH session ended. You know that Capistrano runs every command in a separate SSH session, right? So there's no connection.

Comment: So are you trying to verify the server came up ok? Most init scripts are written to start a server as a daemon in the background, spit out server started ok and go.

Comment: Hmm, maybe not verify that it came back up, but just show the text of what the init script says "app has been started" rather than the default "ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'"